# jquery mobile rangeslider when it hit max value add + sign

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am wondering how to add a plus (+) sign to Jquery Mobile range slider the higher value when the max value is selected/hit. 
For [example](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Philadelphia--PA--United-States?checkin=11%2F13%2F2014&checkout=11%2F19%2F2014&guests=2) on the price top range, it has a + when the max value is selected.

I tried changing the max value  `<input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="400" max="2000+" value="1500" step="50">`
it didnt work, also tried to change it with script, but it didnt work either. Not sure if it is possible to do so.

```
  <script>
  $(document).on('pageshow',function(){
    var value = document.getElementById("range-1b").value;
    if(value =2000){
     document.getElementById("range-1b").value="2000+";
    }
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle version?

Comment: This is not my fiddle but this is the exact same fiddle i am talking about http://jsfiddle.net/eric_mesaros/7cwv81qk/

Comment: @Ben you can fork the fiddle and make your own version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When jQM enhances the rangeslider, the inputs are set to type="number". This type only accepts numbers, so the text '100+' cannot be set as the value of the input.

One workaround could be to just position a '+' next to the 100:

In the rangeslider markup, add a `<span>` with a class of labelPlus:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider">
    <label for="range-1a">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="40" />
    <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="80" />
    <span class="labelPlus">+</span>
</div>
```

Use the labelPlus class CSS to initially hide the span and absolutely position it in the correct spot:

```
.labelPlus{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    width: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-right: 18px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

In javascript, handle the change event on the high input and check to see if we are at 100. If so, show the plus sign span, otherwise hide it:

```
$("#range-1b").on("change", function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (parseInt(val) >= 100) {
        $(".labelPlus").show(); 
    } else {
        $(".labelPlus").hide();
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ENzY7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

you need to work with the ochange event to achieve this.

I have made it myself with the default one from the Jquery UI.Check out

```
$(function () {
      $("#slider-range").slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 500,
          values: [75, 300],
          slide: function (event, ui) {
              console.log($("#amount").val());
              //console.log($("#amount").text());
              var dol = getSecondPart($("#amount").val());
              if (ui.values[1] == '500') {
                  if (dol == ' $499' || dol == ' $500+') {
                      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + "500+");
                  }
              }
              else {
                  $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
              }
          }
      });
      $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
        " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
  });
  function getSecondPart(str) {
      return str.split('-')[1];
  }
```

Check out the fiddle version

http://jsfiddle.net/cwfL3agn/